# How to secure Drupal webform confirmation URL querystring values?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-webform

I got the following confirmation URL after submitting webform:

```
localhost/dfilpd6/?q=node/1/done&sid=20
```

I want to secure the "sid" so that the user will not able to change the "sid".
How could i generate random sid or is there something else i can implement.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set a custom 'redirect location' in the webform form settings (Edit webform node > Form settings tab > Redirection location)